# Is [*-lang] an acceptable tag? And [factor] discussion

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The [factor](/questions/tagged/factor) says:

> Factor is a concatenative programming language that was influenced by Forth, Joy and Lisp.

Fair enough, but only 27 of the 191 question tagged [factor](/questions/tagged/factor) are related to the Factor programming language (unless R and Factor are close friends). And worse yet, there are only 2 questions in the last 18 months about the programming language.

So, rather than retagging 164 questions and having this issue likely creep up again in the future, I figured let's change [factor](/questions/tagged/factor) to mean ... something else, and let's create a new tag [factor-lang](/questions/tagged/factor-lang) for the programming language.

Is this acceptable?

It terms of what [factor](/questions/tagged/factor) should mean, it looks like quite a few of the questions are related to some construct in R, perhaps this should be it's new meaning. If so, this is perhaps best handled by someone that actually knows R (I don't).

Alternatively we can make [factor](/questions/tagged/factor) and [factors](/questions/tagged/factors) synonyms.

I'll retag the 27 questions if using [factor-lang](/questions/tagged/factor-lang) is decided.

Comment: Why? We don't use [c++-lang], [c#-lang], etc.

Comment: No, “a factor” shouldn’t be a tag and people need to learn to read the excerpts.

Comment: @minitech As long as there are new users, there will always be people who don't read excerpts. So [tag:factors] is a bad tag then? Either way, that's kind of the meaning I was going for.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yes, I think [tag:factors] is a bad tag, and no, I don’t think [tag:factor] should mean that.

Comment: @johnson because there isnt huge miss use of the c++ tag

Comment: I admit I'm not that familiar with either R or Factor, but it appears that a factor in R is a data type (and judging from the number of questions, a rather common one), and we do have tags for data types, e.g., [tag:function-pointers].

Comment: If the tag really is important to R, it should get an [tag:r-factor] tag, not just take over the main one. Easier != Better.

Comment: Is it possible to auto-correct the tags on a question that has [tag:r] and [tag:factor] to have [tag:r] and [tag:r-factor]?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler There isn't currently functionality to do that, but you could post a feature request requesting that such functionality be implemented, although I doubt it will.

Comment: The tag is used for R more than anything else by a wide margin.  `factor` is the name of a fundamental datatype in the R language -- as fundamental as `int` is for the C language.  `factors` would not be seen as a synonym for an R factor.  (Note that the R and Factor languages are not related in any way.)

Answer (score 7):

I think that given the ambiguous name [factor-lang](/questions/tagged/factor-lang) or [factor-language](/questions/tagged/factor-language) would be acceptable.

A brief search shows similar examples for specific languages, although even the suffixes used are not consistent: [julia-lang](/questions/tagged/julia-lang), [slim-lang](/questions/tagged/slim-lang), [q-lang](/questions/tagged/q-lang), [golang](/questions/tagged/golang), [cg-language](/questions/tagged/cg-language), [curl-language](/questions/tagged/curl-language), [nice-language](/questions/tagged/nice-language), [false-language](/questions/tagged/false-language)

I also think that [r-factor](/questions/tagged/r-factor) is more appropiate for the R datatype.

Comment: I imagine it's easier to persuade people to use [tag:factor-lang] instead of having the R folks to use something else when the tags are being auto-completed. A person interested in the language would notice, while anyone else wouldn't care very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tag [factor-lang](/questions/tagged/factor-lang) is only acceptable because the word "factor" is otherwise ambiguous (it could mean factors of a number or even factoring). This can't apply to the names of other programming languages like [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) or [python](/questions/tagged/python) or even [rust](/questions/tagged/rust), where the terms have only one meaning in software development circles and not, say, as a kind of gem, reptile, or result of a chemical reaction.